# How to get the Multiple Column in from the Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel-8

I have a laravel collection with relation data. I want to get only some columns in the result array.
How can I get this?
The output should be:

```
[['id'=> 3, 'name'=>'John'],['id'=>5, 'name'=>'Jany']]
```

Answer (score 0):

use Get?

```
Collection::get(['id','name']);
```